# I want to remove systemd from ubuntu and replace it with runit

Tags: linux, ubuntu, systemd, init

I want to remove `systemd` off my system because I use Void Linux and I had to dual boot with Ubuntu but there is `systemd` and don't understand it well. Thus I want to change to `runit` but I would like to know if this will affect `apt` or not. If not, how do I approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is possible to do it, I ***strongly*** advise against doing it. Replacing an init system is no simple task, especially with systemd, as *A LOT* of things depend on it, some legitimatly, some for some unknown, probably idiotic, reasons.

Actually, while I think about it, a lot of you ubuntu desktop packages probably hard depend on it.
So, no it should not be possible.

If you have trouble understanding systemd, fret not, as there are many good resources on the web, e.g [the arch linux wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/systemd)

If you have any particular question, you should either ask that question, or try searching for it.